# Inserting a string in a cell reference

Tags: excel

I have in a cell ("I8") the name of the sheet and I in another cell I want to get the value of a cell that is located in a different workbook but has the same name.

I've tried:

```
='[Results.xlsx]'&I8&'!$P$2
```

But I get an error. I've tried using `"` but I also get an error. I've done this already but I haven't got the excel file with me.

Comment: Is the other workbook open or closed? If it's closed, can it be opened (with code, temporarily)? If its open, @Tim 's answer will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Indirect()`

```
=INDIRECT("'[Results.xlsx]" & I8 & "'!$P$2")
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the tip but in Excel 2007 it does no work. I get "REF!

Comment: The other workbook has to be open. Is it?

Comment: Please accept my apologies. The workbook name is not Results but something else. It works 100%!